# Java OOP encapsulation. Why is Object.doSomething(); better than doSomething(Object);?

Tags: java, oop

I am struggling to explain oop concepts in java.

A major tenet in oop is that objects have methods; so Object.method(); works.
I am contrasting this with procedural programming in which one must do method(Object).

Is this called encapsulation?

What are the advantages of the oop way?

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but why are you explaining these concepts to anyone if you don't understand them? Or did you mean that you're struggling to *understand* these concepts?

Comment: move this question to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 more advantages of OOP are re-use and polymorphism.

**ReUse:**
If you use `doSomething(Object)` in one file or one program, it may work fine for that program.  Now, imagine that you need to use your `Object` in another program.  You will need to duplicate the `doSomething()` method in your new program (probably copy and paste it).  This may work, but is bad practice and makes maintaining that logic a nightmare.  If the `doSomething()` logic is a function inside `Object` then that logic "lives" with the object.

**Polymorphism:**
Imagine another case where Object is just one of many similar types.  If you take advantage of Interfaces, many objects can implement the `doSomething()` function to suit their specific needs.

Example:

```
interface ICar
{
    void doSomething();
    void getFuel();
}

class GasCar : ICar
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        //do something a gas car would do
    }
    public void getFuel()
    {
        //logic to pull gas out of a tank
    }
}

class ElectricCar : ICar
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        //do something an electric car would do
    }
    public void getFuel()
    {
        //logic to pull fuel out of a battery
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's a big question with an answer that fills multiple books, but in short, class members have access modifiers (public, private, protected). Private members can be accessed by other class members, such as a method, but not from external functions.

Answer (score 2):

In the scenario **Object.doSomething()**, the object will have  complete control over its properties which are used in the method.

But in the other call, **doSomething(Object)**, you have to make all the properties of the object public so that they are available in the method. Which is not a safer operation.

Comment: hmmm, what if in scenario 2 I have private properties that are accessible with getter/setters? Wouldn't they still be available??

Comment: @Gevorg They are but in getter/setter you still have control over those private properties and you will show them as you want to the outside classes.

Comment: @Gevorg As I understand your comment, yes they would be accessible and many people code exactly as you are thinking, doSomething(obj.getValue1(), obj.getValue2()).  This is a known bad OO pattern.

Answer (score 1):

One other answer to keep in mind.  When you do method(object) and method is implemented like this:

```
method(obj)
{
    return obj.getA()+obj.getB()
}
```

This is bad because later when you want to do the same thing again, where is your code?  I mean, it uses A and B, so the first place you'd go to look is obj, but it's not there!?!  Now you have to go search.

OO is as much about organizing code to find and reuse it as anything else.

tl;dr rant

You see a LOT of code like this with the bean pattern--I've come to see beans as one of the more insidious evils in OO programming because of this.  In theory most beans these days are called "Pojos" because you CAN implement actual methods in them, but people still stick with beans full of nothing but setters and getters which is in no way OO, in fact they encourage code that is specifically NOT OO (beans are more akin to data structures in a non-oo language like C than anything OO has).

Answer (score 0):

OOP evangelizes encapsulation; as a result, state and behavior is encapsulated in the class representing the object. Depending on what level you the encapsulation to happen, employ either static (class level) or instance (object level) based encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

method(Object) is a paradigm that works with data structures. Data Structures are about grouping fields of information that are semantically consistent and related (i.e. struct Person {FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth}).

Object oriented programing is one step above data structures. In OOP, we not only group data fields that are related, but we also include functions (methods, member functions) that are related to the data (and that act on the data the correct way).

Encapsulation is about keeping part of the members private to objects. The goal is to "hide" the inner-working from the external world, and protect the object's state from "corruption", or from being assigned incorrect values. OOP languages provide several "access modifiers" that are used to specify whether a given member can be accessed by a specific category of objects (instances of child classes, classes in the same "package/namespace/library", any other class, etc.).

object.method() is usually about asking an object to perform something that may involve accessing a field that is not accessible outside of the class.

The above was to define, and explain how the concept of member function (method), and the concept of encapsulation go hand in hand.

```
Referrences:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming
```